# fullcalendar slots widths are not same for same duration and slots are interchanged

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I have slots with same time duration but it's width is different.
it should be in one column.

My Event Source ::[Source File](http://www.filedropper.com/jsonresponse)

[image]
1. Iterchanged same color slot issue resolved by adding 1+ second in  "start" time of same event's slots in Json response.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set [slotEventOverlap](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/agenda/slotEventOverlap/) property in the calendar to false:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    slotEventOverlap: false //Boolean, default: true
});
```

It only applies to the agendaWeek and agendaDay views.

Comment: Actually at my end it is not overlapping but same duration slots width are different see my first column that i have pointed out. Also i have added slotEventOverlap:false but it is not working